# MVVM Light and windows phone RTW any gotchas

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

Are there any gotchas using mvvm-light and the RTW windows phone 7 tools? 
There was a hotfix back in July but is there a new one in the pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes between the Beta & Release version don't have any major changes comparable to those introduced in the move from CTP (Refresh) to Beta.
Hopefully MVVM-Light is without impact, but it's still officially a Beta so expect a release version  to come - hopefully quite soon.
Of course if you find any issues as a result of the change to RTM - please share them.

Comment: I was guessing that would be the state of play, but I'll start using whats there.

Answer (score 1):

There's still a problem with the Template when using an actual device.

Check this question for more info:
[MVVMLight and WP7 RTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796372/mvvmlight-and-wp7-rtm/3798781#3798781)

Comment: Cheers for that. Hardly the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using MVVM Light on some WP7 apps for the last few days (with the RTW version of the dev. tools), and all I had to do was use the fix to make it work like a charm!

So, the fix for the Beta version is still required on the RTW version, at least for now!

Comment: The fix form the beta was to do with (amongst a few other things) the amalgamation of assemblies in to `Microsoft.Phone.dll`. The old template had all the separate assemblies and so didn't work. As the assemblies haven't been split out again, the hotfix is still necessary.