# MVVMLight and WP7 RTM

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

Does the MVVMLight version that worked before with the WP7 Beta work with WP7 RTM?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780210/mvvm-light-and-windows-phone-rtw-any-gotchas

Answer (score 3):

It sure does, but the one gotcha that still exists.

If you're using the templates, is that it doesn't set the ProductID uniquely.  While you tend not to see this problem pop up on the emulator, it can cause big problems on an actuall device as the device get's confused with what application is what.

To fix the problem, open up the Properties\WMAppManifest.xml file and modify the ProductID attribute on the App element.  The easiest way to do this is to create a dummy WP7 Project (non-MVVMLight) and copy the ProductID from there.

Answer (score 0):

I use the binaries, the snippets and the item templates, but I do not currently use the Project templates. Laurent is working on an update to the framework that includes some cool new features (http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2011/02/08/mvvm-light-v4-preview-bl0014-release-notes.aspx) and I'm hoping that he also addresses the project templates and the installation process :)

Cheers!
Chris

http://chriskoenig.net | @chriskoenig